# $1$-periodic mod-$2$ K-theory

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, kt.k-theory-and-homology, stable-homotopy

Complex $K$-theory mod $2$ is $2$-periodic, $K/2_* = \mathbf{F}_2[u,u^{-1}]$. Is there an extension $K/2 \to K'$ of ring spectra such that $K'_*=\mathbb{F}_2[q,q^{-1}]$ with $|q|=1$ and such that the generator $u$ of $K/2_*$ maps to $q^2$? If so, can $K'$ be chosen to be homotopy commutative?

Comment: Yes, you can just take $K'=K/2\vee\Sigma K/2$ and define the product in an obvious way on each of the four summands of $K'\wedge K'$.  The product on $K/2$ is noncommutative but there is a derivation $Q$ of degree $1$ with $ab+ba=u^{-1}Q(a)Q(b)$.  The product on $K'$ will have the same property.

Comment: @NeilStrickland right, of course, thanks! Is it correct that there is no homotopy commutative ring spectrum with period 1 and coefficients an $\mathbb F_2$-algebra that isn't just a wedge of $H\mathbb F_2$?

Comment: @Tilman any homotopy commutative ring spectrum with 2=0 is automatically a wedge of HF_2's (this is proven by Hopkins in his thesis "stable decompositions of certain loop spaces" in section 2.2)